# Confused with <?>,<? extends Object>,<? super Object> in java generics

Tags: java, generics

```
List<?> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<? extends Object> l2 = l1;
```

no compile error here, however

```
List<?> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<? super Object> l2 = l1;
```

there is a compile error. It's so confused!

Comment: First start here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super  Then you need to read some actual documentation.  I found the explanations in *Learning Java* by O'Reilly to be pretty good on generics.  The short answer is that nothing (?) can be the super class of `Object` so that one is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting any type into the diamond.

```
List<?> l1 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Now:

```
List<? extends Object> l2 = l1;
```

Yup, `String` extends `Object`.

```
List<? super Object> l2 = l1;
```

Nope, `String` is not a supertype of `Object`.

Comment: yeah, thanks a lot buddy, I am not confused now haha